# Am I understanding this sentence by Tolkien correctly?

Tags: grammar, british-english

> I hope that my inadequate knowledge of Swedish - no better than my **kn.** of Dutch, but I possess **a *v.* much better** Dutch dictionary! - tends to exaggerate the impression I received. The impression remains, nonetheless, that Dr. Ohlmarks is a conceited person, less competent than charming Max Schuchart, though he thinks much better of himself.
>
> [[Wikipedia]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Translation_of_The_Lord_of_the_Rings_into_Swedish)

1. Does the "less competent than charming Max Schuchart" part mean that Dr. Ohlmarks is less competent than "the" charming Max Schuchart? Or something else? Can you really leave out "the" there?
2. Why does Tolkien use "kn." for "knowledge" and "v." for "very"? (Assuming that's what the "v." means.)
3. Is "a very much better" really correct English? I assume so, since it's Tolkien, but it sounds very strange to me.

Comment: Does "a very much better X" seem strange to you for any particular reason? It seems like standard English to me. (A dictionary. A better dictionary. A much better dictionary. A very much better dictionary.)

Answer (score 1):

1. Yes, it does, and you can in an informal context like this.
2. V. for *very* is a v. common abbreviation, kn. much less so (but he has written it out in full in the previous clause).
3. "I have a Dutch dictionary [which is] very much better [than the Swedish dictionary I used]."

This is evidently an informal letter to someone he knows well.